# Selecting a default value for a dropdown (key-value array) in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Here is the dropdown in a form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', array('id'=>'initials','label'=>'Customer', 'value'=>$customers));
```

The $customers is a key-value array like this:

```
array(
(int) 2 => 'Best customer',
(int) 5 => 'Good customer',
(int) 9 => 'Customer')
```

I need one value to be pre selected once the dropdown is created. I have tried to select a default value as the int id and as the customer name but none of them worked.

Here is the controller edit function:

```
function edit($id = null) {

    $this->Project->id=$id;

    $this->Project->recursive = 0;

    $customers = $this->Customer->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('company_id'=>$this->Auth->user('company_id'))));
    $this -> set('customers', $customers);


    if(!$this->Project->exists()){
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid project');
    }

    if($this->request->is('post')|| $this->request->is('put')){

        if($this->Project->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The project has been edited');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'projects', 'action'=>'view', $id));
        } else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('The project could not be edited. Please, try again');
        }
        }else{
            $this->request->data = $this->Project->read();
            $this->request->data['Project']['customer_id'] = 'New customer';
        }

    }
```

And here is the edit form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Project');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php __('Edit Project'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', array('id'=>'initials','label'=>'Customer', 'value'=>$customers)); 
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('project_nr', array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>'Case number'));
    echo $this->Form->input('address');
    echo $this->Form->input('post_nr');
    echo $this->Form->input('city');
    echo $this->Form->input('start_date', array('label'=>'Start Date', 'class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text'));
    echo $this->Form->input('finish_date', array('label'=>'End Date', 'class'=>'datepicker', 'type'=>'text'));
    echo $this->Form->input('company_id', array('value' => $current_user['company_id'], 'type'=>'text', 'type'=>'hidden'));


?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
```

Comment: Never use "value" in your form directly (`'value'=>$customers`), it kills the "state of the form" after a POST on invalidation. Also dont use read(). Use find() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to leverage the controller for this

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Model->create();
    if ($this->Model->save($this->request->data)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    /* Now here you can put your default values */
    $this->request->data['Model']['field'] = ...;
}
```

For details see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Comment: I have tried to set it this way:

$this->request->data['Project']['customer_id'] == $customer_id;

But what I get is always the first item in the array to be selected.

Comment: Why two `==`? Tip: Post your form. The way your array data looks like when you debug `$this->request->data` then is how it should look like to pre-select the correct default values.

Comment: I have added the controller function and the form to the question.

The == was a typo in the answer.

Comment: Is your form valid? Where is the `$this->Form->create()` etc?

Comment: yes, ofcourse, have reuploaded the full form, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: `$this->request->data['Project']['customer_id'] = 'New customer';` You need to pass a valid ID (probably 9 in your case) that is present as key in the `$customers` array you pass down to the view. Not a random string. And remove all your custom `value` stuff in the form. It's bad.

Comment: But if I remove the value in the form, how would I pass the array of choices?

Comment: the array of choices is already passed with `$customers` - CakePHP will automatically use that array to populate the select. And your passed down default value from the controller to pre-select the right value.

Comment: Oh it seems stating the array was the problem.
Now it works perfectly well. Thanks a bunch